# How to add audio file to longtable?

Tags: longtable, media9, audio

I am trying to make a long table that includes embedded audio files. Whenever I try adding files with media9, LaTeX won't create a pdf. Any suggestions on how to make a long table with embedded audio files and a clickable icon that plays it in the appropriate column?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\rr}{\raggedright} %allows for left alignment
\newcommand{\tn}{\tabularnewline}
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{@{}p{.5cm} p{1cm} p{2cm} p{2cm} p{1cm} p{2cm} p{3cm}@{}}
\caption{Swadesh List}\\
\toprule
 & Audio & Gloss & \rr Phonemic Transcription & Tonemes & \rr Phonetic Transcription    & \rr Notes on translation\tn
\midrule

\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{4}{c}%
{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
\toprule
 & Audio & Gloss & \rr Phonemic Transcription & Tonemes & \rr Phonetic Transcription & \rr Notes on translation\tn
\midrule
\endhead
\toprule \multicolumn{4}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

1. & \includemedia[
width=1cm,
height=1cm,
activate=onclick,
addresource=1.mp3,
transparent=false,
flashvars={source=1.mp3}
]{}{VPlayer.swf} & big & \textipa{/\!b\'e\t{tS}:/} & H & \textipa{[\!b\'E\t{tC}:]} & \rr also: `respected'; `important'\tn
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: if it works in a `tabular` ? it should work in longtable, does it work if you use `\mbox{\includemedia..` so `\includemedia` isn't the first thing in the cell?

Comment: This is a bug in `media9` that has already been fixed as of v0.46; current is 0.48.

Comment: Also note that you need `APlayer.swf` to play audio, not `VPlayer.swf`.

Comment: After updating to texlive2014, it worked. Thanks for pointing that out.